# Database migrations: manage with build script or automatic on app startup?

Tags: deployment, build-process, database-migration

I'm in the process of developing a deployment system for a new web app and I'm wondering where the best point in the process to manage database migrations is (the question of how to do the migrations is another problem entirely).

It seems there are two ways to go:

1. Use a migration script that can
   either be run manually from command
   line or as part of the automatic
   deployment/build process
2. Run the migrations when the app
   starts up (I'm using ASP.NET so this
   can be done easily enough without
   causing a long-running user request)

Does anyone have any suggestions/insight/experience with these approaches? Any other suggestions?

I can see why #1 might be more attractive - it gives me complete control over when the DB is updated. However, I quite like #2 as it allows me to quickly iterate between deployments and reduces the manual process. #2 could also be used on my development machine to allow even quicker iterations. Hmm, starting to think having both might be a good thing...

Answer (score 2):

We have a sales-force system with ~100 client and we are updating database at application startup (True, our is a desktop application.) I like this approach, it's safe and iterative if we have indeterministic startpoint (is the client database new or only updated to verison x.y.z?).

But at serverside I'm preferr your #1 option: we create a SQL query file on our virtual machine (based on the copy of the original database) and runs this query against the real server.

So IMHO:

- **Disconnected clients:** startup, iterative scripts
- **Server:** query created on VM based on the actual and real database

So I'm interrested in this problem too, and find some (half)frameworks as [RikMigrations](http://www.rikware.com/RikMigrations.html). After some googling there is a good startplace about DB versioning/migration frameworks: [.NET Database Migration Tool Roundup](http://flux88.com/blog/net-database-migration-tool-roundup/). Not neccessarely the documentation but the team blogs can be interresting.

Answer (score 1):

I like option #1 better as it seems much more flexible.  In lieu of actually performing migrations on each app start, I think I would verify that the database schema (version number?) matches the code, and if not, throw a warning or error about a mismatched database schema.

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer option #1 for a number of reasons. First, integration tests usually require your DB schema to be up-to-date, and launching a web-site to upgrade the schema will be a huge timewaster. Second, you cannot change database schema while your site is running (say, add a couple of indexes to speed things up).

As for production side of things, upgrading your database in transaction MSI-style installation is much better than attempting to upgrade at each app startup since you can potentially end up with desynchronized database-application versions.

And if you're looking for the migration framework, take a look at [Wizardby](http://code.google.com/p/octalforty-wizardby/).

Answer (score 0):

If the application ever has to run on a customer's machine than migrating at startup can prevent a lot of support calls - assuming you can do seamless migration without user intervention (I hope you aren't normally running your web app with permission to modify the database).

If the application always runs under your control automatic migration is less of an issue - but still can be a good feature, especially if you want to minimize downtime and manual deployment steps.